# FancyBox Form Submission

Tags: php, ajax, forms, fancybox

I have been looking around online on how to get a web form to work inside of FancyBox. The form displays correctly, but when I press submit, it submits and adds a row to the database, but everything is blank (meaning its not really adding the data). In addition to this, it does not show a response to say if the message has been sent in the lightbox or not. I reviewed other questions similar to this and found out that AJAX is used to submit it. Ive never really used AJAX before so I am not for sure what is wrong. I have also used FireBug and it does not show any data transmitting.

Code for Form:

```
<div style="display: none">
<div id="contact">
This form will allow you to contact our staff support team. This can be used to request ban     reversals, login problems, etc. Just note, all responses will be sent via e-mail.<br />Be sure you  leave us a valid e-mail and to be sure you check this email often and to check your spam folders if you do not receive a response.<br /><br /><center>
<form action="" method="post" id="contactus">
Your Name:  <input type="text" STYLE="color: black;  background-color: white;" name="name" value="" /><br />
Your Email: <input type="text" STYLE="color: black;  background-color: white;" name="email" value="" /><br /><br />
Your Message: <br /><br /><textarea rows="10" cols="70" STYLE="color: black;  background-color: white;" name="textarea" value=""></textarea><br /><br />
<input type="submit" STYLE="color: black;  background-color: white;" value="Submit Message" />    </form><br /></center>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the AJAX Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox();
});
</script>

$("#contact").bind("submit", function() {

    $.fancybox.showActivity();

    $.ajax({
        type        : "POST",
        cache       : false,
        url         : "outsidesupport_processed.php",
        data        : $(this).serializeArray(),
        success     :function(data){
                        $.fancybox(data);
                     }
    });

    return false;
});

});     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Debugg data add
alert(data); in success

```
success :function(data){
                           $.fancybox(data);
                           alert(data);
                     }
```

Are there any errors?

This is syntax error:

```
</script>

$("#contact").bind("submit", function() {
```

check 
var test = $(this).serializeArray();
if test is not null, maybe error is here outsidesupport_processed.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made the adjustments, however, the same thing is still happening. Here is the new AJAX action. http://pastebin.com/qSCGgtXi It still just adds blanks, so maybe the problem isnt with this code but with the script that added the information into the database? Do we need to include AJAX on outsidesupport_processed.php for this to work? Right now that page is fully PHP/HTML